# I am providing a quotation for work and I want to include the currency notation. We are both in the same country. Is it appropriate?

Tags: money

I am providing a quotation for work and I want to include the currency notation.  My potential client and myself are both in the same country.

Is it appropriate to use the currency notation?

1. I know that if I'm doing things internationally and potentially dealing with clients that are based in a different country than my company, that I would want to be clear which currency I am quoting in.
2. What is not clear to me and has been hard for me to search on, has been whether to include the currency notation or not.
3. I've asked around in "real life" and I've heard varying accounts without any references.  Mainly it ended up being a discussion on culture and customs boiling down to "whether it might offend them".   But I'm not convinced.

for example

Can I use both or just one?

a. Hi im bob i'm going to do xyz for you and it will cost you $400.

b. Hi im bob i'm going to do xyz for you and it will cost you $400 USD.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to English Language and Usage! This question seems like it may be better suited to The Workplace stack exchange, as it deals primarily with what is appropriate re: professionalism rather than grammatically.

Comment: If both are in the US, no need to use USD, as the $ sign already means USD here. However, you can do better than "it will cost you," which is not common or not appealing to hear. Use "XYZ at a (cost) OR (charge) of $400.00.

Comment: thanks Cameron. my cursory scan of the ~200 stack exchange options didn't jump out at me when i first posed the question. I tried to find the right place :D Just not hard enough!   I flagged my own question to be moved.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok to say it either way:

> Hi, I'm Bob. I'm going to do XYZ at a cost of $400.

or

> Hi, I'm Bob. I'm going to do XYZ at a cost of $400 USD.

It's most common to use the first example when both parties are in the US because the local currency is assumed. Specifying USD is also correct and optional and could imply that you also provide services to clients in other countries.

If both parties were in Canada, for example, CAD would be assumed.

Comment: Technically the second should be "... cost of 400 USD."  The dollar sign is redundant if "USD" is specified.

Comment: @HotLicks: Or USD 400.